# if uncooked shabudana( Tapioca) is soaked for 2 day i put this mixture in fridge, is it still safe to eat (after it's cooked)?

Tags: sous-vide

i put shabudana mixture into dish and put it into fridge ater two day i see this mixture .if uncooked shabudana( Tapioca) is it still safe to eat (after it's cooked)?

Comment: I tried to look up an exact duplicate but could not find it in 1 minute. But I bet your question has already been answered in some form: there are 430 questions [when you seach for 'safe to eat'](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+safe+to+eat)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you soaked it in outside room temperature (how hot was the weather?) and then put it in fridge after two days? Does the soaked mixture have any 'odd' smell coming from it? That is one way to tell if it is not good. Cooking might kill any yeast or bacteria, but if other toxins have been prepared by those germs then those might still be present. If you can afford to throw it, please do. By that, I mean, compost it or something if you can.